# What does the ?rand= in a url do in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I held down the refresh button (F5) on a webpage being served by a django development server running Django version 1.7.1, and after a while a ?rand= started to appeared in the url, like so:

```
"GET /home/?rand=0.8159500481560826 HTTP/1.1" 200 45211
"GET /home/?rand=0.46161260246299207 HTTP/1.1" 200 45211
"GET /home/?rand=0.8125064456835389 HTTP/1.1" 200 45211
```

What is it used for?
Should I take it into account somehow?

Comment: Looks like a URL parameter.

Comment: it generates a different url every time, forcing your browser to actually query the server despite of possible cache mechanisms, and forcing your server to not reply 304

Comment: like @njzk2 said, it gives you the same page, but under a different url.  `rand` is not a special value, it could be anything. the idea is just have something unique added on the end of the url